# I'm getting hard edges in subdivided mesh when I render. It looks different in the viewport

Tags: rendering

My problem is :

how i want it to be ( Viewport Shading)

[image: how i want it to be ( Viewport Shading)]

Weird Distortion on crotch & armpit

[image: Weird Distortion on crotch & armpit]

The first image is how I want it to be, and was taken on "Viewport Shading" on the top right section.

The second image is how it turns out when I press F12 and render it (both eevee and cycles result in the same way).

Here are the things I've already tried but did not work out :

- Recalculating normals ( I have no idea what it does lol )
- Increasing qaulity of subdivision surface modifier

Some other things that might help are :

- Currently armature bones are parented with the body part.
- I am using Blender 2.9.
- The objects are all smooth shading enabled.

Comment: In the subdivision surface modifier, there are separate controls for the Viewport and Render with regards to how many subdivision levels are applied. Check your modifier and make sure the numbers match. - Secondly, make sure there are no hidden objects in your viewport - hidden objects still show up in renders. Lastly, shading artifacts can be the result of n-gons - (non-quad) faces - especially on curved edges or faces. You could try a Remesh Modifier if this is the case.

Comment: Hey, I edited my first comment to add more. Maybe some of that will be helpful then? If you could post your .blend file (or a minimized version), we could help further. You can do it here - https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/

Comment: Hi! It was my hidden backup object collection overlapping on the render screen. Thank you so much for your help. I was stuck on this for an hour. I really appreciate it! :)))